# Scan for subnets on a LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, subnet

This is a fairly basic question. Is there a way to scan for subnets or all devices on a network? Using `nmap -sn 192.168.1.1` returns only devices on `192.168.1.X`. I am trying to scan for subnets such as `192.168.70.1`, without knowing the subnet to target in nmap.

An example of this usage would be logging into an unfamiliar network to find subnets to scan for devices. My wifi for example is set up on a subnet, but vpn into the router puts me on `192.168.1.1`. How would I scan to find devices or the subnet for wifi without knowing the subnet.

Comment: A network scan cannot find subnets. It can find hosts.

Comment: Any recommendations for discovering ip of hosts without knowing the subnet?

Comment: well, what address spec are you  giving nmap? `192.168.0.0/16`? it'll be a slow scan, but it will iterate from .0.1 - .255.254.